# how to pipe in first name with macro in outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, macros

I'm using a marketing template in outlook and would like to include multiple recipients from a outlook distribution list.

Ideally, I would like the template to pull the first name from each of the contacts from the address book of outlook 2010 and customize each email for the template.  So the message will read:

Hello First Name,

(outlook template message).

This way it looks like a personal email to all recipient.  I know this is super basic but I am very new with macros. Can someone help me?

Comment: We are not a script-writing service here at SuperUser, but we're happy to help you once you've gotten something started and come up against something you cannot figure out. Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, there are no this kind of macros in Outlook (replaceable in text). But you can write your custom VBA macro for that.